Proving combinatorics identity using reasoning
I want to prove this identity using reasoning rather than expansions:
$$
\mathcal{P}(n,r)=\mathcal{P}(n-1,r)+r\cdot\mathcal{P}(n-1,r-1)
$$
Where $\mathcal{P}(n,r)$ the number of permutations of all the possible $r$-subsets of $n$ objects.
$$
\mathcal{P}(n,r)=r!\binom{n}{r}
$$
I understand that the first term of the RHS is the number of ways to pick (in order) $r$ objects from $n$ objects, after picking away an object, but have not been able to weave together the first and second term to form the LHS.

Right, I’ll correct it

$P(n,r)$ = Number of ways of selecting a permutation of r objects from a set of size $n$.
Let the set be denoted by $A$. Let its elements be $\{a_1,a_2,\ldots a_n\}$. You can decompose the set of all possible permutation into these two subsets:
Set $B$ = set of all permutations in which the element $a_1$ is not present.
Set $C$ = set of all permutations in which the element $a_1$ is present.
Then $|B| = P(n-1,r)$.
To get $|C|$, we can make a selection containing $a_1$ in the following way:
Choose a permutation of $r-1$ elements from the set $A\setminus \{a_1\}$. Then from this permutation, we want to create a permutation of size $r$. So, from each permutation of length $r-1$, contructed from the set $A\setminus\{a_1\}$, we can make $r$ permutations by changing the position of $a_1$.
So, $$|C| = r\cdot P(n-1,r-1)$$
And $$|A| = |B|+|C|$$

It is simpler to express the logic if you transform permutations to combinations.
If you correct your expression, as pointed out by Gwen,
since $P(n,r) = r!C(n,r),\;$it can be reduced to
$r![C(n,r) = C(n-1,r) + C(n-1,r-1)]$,
$\implies \;C(n,r) = C(n-1,r) + C(n-1,r-1)$
which is the well known Pascal's identity, and can be understood as breaking up a committee of $r$ people from $n,\,$ $C(n,r)\,$ into two disjoint parts  and adding them up, viz.
a committee without a particular person, $C(n-1,r)$
$+$ a committee with that particular person $C(n-1,r-1)$
